# Getting "ValueError: concat() expects at least one object!" in a simple python code block

Tags: python, nltk, jupyter-notebook

I ran the following code block in my IPython notebook and got a valueerror. I am not able to figure out whether it is a syntactical error.

```
import sys
sys.version
```

would give me

```
'2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 18 2014, 16:57:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

and on running

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
[(genre, word) for genre in brown.categories() for word in brown.words(categories=genre) ]
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-884c4187e29a> in <module>()
  1 from nltk.corpus import brown
----> 2 [(genre, word) for genre in brown.categories() for word in brown.words(categories=genre) ]

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\tagged.pyc in words(self, fileids, categories)
198     def words(self, fileids=None, categories=None):
199         return TaggedCorpusReader.words(
--> 200             self, self._resolve(fileids, categories))
201     def sents(self, fileids=None, categories=None):
202         return TaggedCorpusReader.sents(

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\tagged.pyc in words(self, fileids)
 81                                         self._para_block_reader,
 82                                         None)
---> 83                        for (fileid, enc) in self.abspaths(fileids, True)])
 84 
 85     def sents(self, fileids=None):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.pyc in concat(docs)
412         return docs[0]
413     if len(docs) == 0:
--> 414         raise ValueError('concat() expects at least one object!')
415 
416     types = set(d.__class__ for d in docs)

ValueError: concat() expects at least one object!"
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

From the traces what is see is there is no categories by name `genre`.

If I just display the categories in brown corpus:

```
for name in brown.categories():
    print name

Outputs:
adventure
belles_lettres
editorial
fiction
government
hobbies
humor
learned
lore
mystery
news
religion
reviews
romance
science_fiction
```

You can use any of the above category present in brown corpus.

Change this to:

```
[(genre, word) for genre in brown.categories() for word in brown.words(categories=genre) ]
```

This:

```
[(genre, word) for genre in brown.categories() for word in brown.words(categories=['news']) ] //Interested in news categories
```

More over what ever category you specify in outer `for loop`, inner `for loop` iterate over all the category in the corpus and hence the output will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, and works for me. It seems that your Brown corpus data, either the text files or the categories file, is corrupted or missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. If I use the solution given above:

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
           (genre, word)
           for genre in brown.categories()
           for word in brown.words(categories='news')) 
genres=['news','religion','hobbies','science_fiction','romance','humor']
modals=['can','could','may','might','must','will']

cfd.tabulate(conditions=genres, samples=modals)
```

Output:

```
                 can could   may might  must  will 
           news    93    86    66    38    50   389 
       religion    93    86    66    38    50   389 
        hobbies    93    86    66    38    50   389 
science_fiction    93    86    66    38    50   389 
        romance    93    86    66    38    50   389 
          humor    93    86    66    38    50   389
```

As you can see, all the rows are the same. The outer for loop iterates over all the categories, but the inner for loop collects words from the genre='news'.

This solution is incorrect.

A workaround is to declare the categories list 'genres' first:

```
genres=['news','religion','hobbies','science_fiction','romance','humor']
       cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
       (genre, word)
       for genre in genres
       for word in brown.words(categories=genre))

cfd.tabulate(conditions=genres, samples=modals)
```

Output:

```
                  can could   may might  must  will 
           news    93    86    66    38    50   389 
       religion    82    59    78    12    54    71 
        hobbies   268    58   131    22    83   264 
science_fiction    16    49     4    12     8    16 
        romance    74   193    11    51    45    43 
          humor    16    30     8     8     9    13
```